# Price Scrape from an ecommerce website google sheets importxml

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

Hi I need to scrape the price from given link but Im getting errors with

```
xpath=IMPORTXML("https://www.tokopedia.com/jktmusicavenue/kawai-cn39-digital-piano-cn-39-cn-39-elektrik-yamaha-hitam","//*[@id="zeus-root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/dd/h3")
```

Comment: @JaSON can you please provide a solution to this issue. Actually it not my field and I came across this for another project.

Comment: I don't think you can extract price from that page. Source code doesn't contain that data

Comment: @DonnyFlaw actually it there. It can be extracted from `<h3 class="css-c820vl" data-testid="lblPDPDetailProductPrice">Rp19.500.000</h3>`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this XPath:

```
"//h3[@data-testid='lblPDPDetailProductPrice']"
```

P.S. Also note that you're using double quotes pair without escaping inside XPath that already surrounded by double-quotes pair

Comment: There is something wrong with the webpage it does not respond to any requests. I have tried writing a script and it works fine with other websites.

Comment: @AQIBABBAS everything seem to be OK. I tried with python-requests and I got required data, **but!** note that you need to add User-agent header , e.g. `'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0'`